# Create database with multiple columns using SQLite in Android Studio

Tags: sqlite

I want to create a database with 3 columns (name of point of interest, longitude and latitude). Since I am completely new to databases I am using an example I found online and try to change it to my case. The problem is it works for 1 column but if I add the other 2 it breaks. This is my code:

#### TaskContract

```cs
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class TaskContract {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "com.example.TodoList.db.tasks";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String POI_NAMES = "tasks";
    public static final String LONGITUDES = "longs";
    public static final String LATITUDES = "lats";

    public class Columns {
        public static final String POI = "task";
        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String LONGITUDE = "long";
        public static final String LATITUDE = "lat";
    }
}
```

#### TaskDBHelper

```cs
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class TaskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TaskDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
        String sqlQuery =
                String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "%s TEXT" + " %s LONGITUDE" + "%s LATITUDE)",
                        TaskContract.POI_NAMES, TaskContract.Columns.POI,
                        TaskContract.LONGITUDES, TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE,
                        TaskContract.LATITUDES, TaskContract.Columns.LATITUDE);

        Log.d("TaskDBHelper","Query to form table: "+sqlQuery);
        sqlDB.execSQL(sqlQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, int i, int i2) {
        sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TaskContract.POI_NAMES+TaskContract.LONGITUDES+TaskContract.LATITUDES);
        onCreate(sqlDB);
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity

and here's my main activity where I add the new values to the columns:

```cs
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    private TaskDBHelper helper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Add a new point of interest");

                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                final TextView inputString1 = new TextView(this); inputString1.setText("Enter name:");
                final TextView inputString2 = new TextView(this); inputString2.setText("Enter longitude:");
                final TextView inputString3 = new TextView(this); inputString3.setText("Enter latitude:");
                final TextView inputString4 = new TextView(this); inputString4.setText("Enter a new point of interest:");

                final EditText inputField1 = new EditText(this);
                final EditText inputField2 = new EditText(this);
                final EditText inputField3 = new EditText(this);
                layout.addView(inputString4);
                layout.addView(inputString1);
                layout.addView(inputField1);
                layout.addView(inputString2);
                layout.addView(inputField2);
                layout.addView(inputString3);
                layout.addView(inputField3);
                builder.setView(layout);


                builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String poi = inputField1.getText().toString();
                        String longit = inputField2.getText().toString();
                        String lat = inputField3.getText().toString();

                        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();


                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.clear();
                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.POI,poi);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.POI_NAMES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);


                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE,longit);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.LONGITUDES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.LATITUDE,lat);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.LATITUDES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);


                        updateUI();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);

                builder.create().show();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.POI_NAMES,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.POI},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.task_view,
                cursor,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.POI},
                new int[]{R.id.taskTextView},
                0
        );

        this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    public void onDoneButtonClick(View view) {
        View v = (View) view.getParent();
        TextView taskTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskTextView);
        String poi = taskTextView.getText().toString();

        String sql = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s'",
                        TaskContract.POI_NAMES,
                        TaskContract.Columns.POI,
                        poi);


        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

#### Problem

I think the problem is when I declare *LONGITUDES* and *LATITUDES* in the TaskContract as if I change them like this:

```cs
public static final String POI_NAMES = "tasks";  
public static final String LONGITUDES = "tasks"; 
public static final String LATITUDES = "tasks";
```

it works but it puts everything in the same column.

Can someone explain what exactly means to assign the values "tasks" to my string?

Answer (score 4):

Your issue appears to be in your SQL syntax, you missed multiple commas:

```
                String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    "%s TEXT" + ", %s LONGITUDE, " + "%s LATITUDE)",
                    TaskContract.POI_NAMES, TaskContract.Columns.POI,
                    TaskContract.LONGITUDES, TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE,
                    TaskContract.LATITUDES, TaskContract.Columns.LATITUDE);
```

You also appear to have more strings in the parameters than you have replacement keys for. This may or may not also be part of your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with  EBrown, but I think the problem is spaces.

```
"CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "%s TEXT" + " %s LONGITUDE" + "%s LATITUDE)",
```

You don't appear to have spaces between your strings. It's been a while since I've done much coding, but maybe you have a table with one field with a long (and weird) name.

Have you run this code and then looked at your database using the SQLite client?